# Push array inside another array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a site develop in php and I have a function where I want to create an array inside other array.
My query are this (i'm using cakephp but in this case is only a problem of array don't tell me to use contain or something like that from cakephp because is a large query and I need to construct my query and my array in this mode)

My array $product_ingredient contain some value.

```
foreach ($product_ingredient as $key) {         
                $ingredient_level1 = $this->ProductIngredientVersion->query('SELECT * FROM ingredients_ingredients
                WHERE ingredients_ingredients.ingredient_id = :ingredient_id
                AND  ingredients_ingredients.product_id = :id 
                AND  ingredients_ingredients.version_id = :version_id 
                AND  ingredients_ingredients.level = 1', array('id' => $id, 'ingredient_id' => $key['products_ingredients']['ingredient_id'], 'version_id' => $key['products_ingredients']['version_id']));


                foreach($ingredient_level1 as $key2){
                    $ingredient_level2 = array($this->ProductIngredientVersion->query('SELECT * FROM ingredients_ingredients
                    WHERE ingredients_ingredients.ingredient_id = :ingredient_id
                    AND  ingredients_ingredients.product_id = :id 
                    AND  ingredients_ingredients.version_id = :version_id 
                    AND  ingredients_ingredients.level = 2', array('id' => $id, 'ingredient_id' => $key2['ingredients_ingredients']['ingredient2_id'], 'version_id' => $key2['ingredients_ingredients']['version_id'])));
                    array_push($ingredient_level1, $ingredient_level2);
                }
                array_push($ingredient_ingredient, $ingredient_level1);
            }
```

The result is that:

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'ingredients_ingredients' => array(
                'id' => '34',
                'level' => '1'
            )
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            (int) 0 => array(
                (int) 0 => array(
                    'ingredients_ingredients' => array(
                        'id' => '35',
                        'level' => '2'
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
```

But I would like this result

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'ingredients_ingredients' => array(
                'id' => '34',
                'level' => '1',
                array(
                    'ingredients_ingredients' => array(
                        'id' => '35',
                        'level' => '2'
                    )
            )
        )
    )
```

How can I solve?

Comment: Are you looking for `array_merge` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)? I'm not really sure what you're going for with the sample arrays as the array you are trying to create is invalid (multiple keys with the same name, etc)

Comment: array_merge append only the array I want the array inside the other array @Dave

Comment: In your desired results code, I believe you have an extra `array(` line right after "modified..." and should replace it with a comma. Correct?

Comment: Yes sorry I have edit the question but is true after modified there is a comma @DouglasA.Crosby

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri Actually you've got that backwards, `array_merge` literally merges the one array into the other while `array_push` treats the array as a stack and appends the new one to it. Are you trying to end with an array that contains all the ingredient levels as a separate stack, or an array that contains an aggregation of all the ingredient levels in the same stack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
array_push($ingredient_ingredient, $ingredient_level1);
```

by

```php
array_push(
    $ingredient_ingredient[0][0]['ingredients_ingredients'],
    $ingredient_level1
);
```

This pushes the array to the appropriate cascade level. However it is very likely that this is the most efficient way, if you're unable to modify SQL or array structure elsewhere.